# NSMutableDictionary most efficient way to apply formula for each value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutableset

I have a NSMutableDictionary with NSNumbers. When I finish building the set I need to recalculate all the values using the currently stored value itself. Now I'm using fast enumeration and storing into a new NSMutableSet, but I'm not experienced in Objective C and there must be a more efficient way to do this:

```
for (id key in temp_target_results) 
{
        formula_score = MyFormula([[temp_target_results objectForKey:key] doubleValue]);

        [target_results setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:formula_score] forKey:key];
}
```

In the end I'm sorting by value (that's why I'm using NSMutableSet).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much more anyone can help you optimize what you are doing because I don't know what's going on behind the scenes (outside of the context of the snippet of code you pasted above, or what's really going on inside your `MyFormula` function).

One optimization question I have would be: why are you storing everything as `NSNumber` objects anyways and not an array of `doubles`? The only advantage (that I can currently see) to doing that is if you're passing your `NSNumber` objects along in an `NSArray`, `NSSet` or `NSDictionary` that gets written out to disk or passed along in an `NSNotification` or.

But some of the things I would do would include getting rid of that extra, unnecessary call to `objectForKey`:

```
for (NSNumber * myNumber in temp_target_results) 
{
   formula_score = MyFormula([myNumber doubleValue]);

   [target_results setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:formula_score] forKey:[myNumber stringValue]];
}
```

Another consideration here:

Your `target_results` appears to not be a `NSMutableSet` because you are doing a `NSMutableDictionary` method of `setObject:forKey:`.  If `target_results` really was a `NSMutableSet`, you'd only need to call:

```
[target_results addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: formula_score]];
```